How to handle dependent macros in Rust
I want to implement some file contents mutation functionality in Rust, but I am a bit lost on how to achieve this using procedural macros. I have an input file that is specified using an environment variable at build time. I want to get the content of this file and apply some mutations to it.
I am aware that nesting macro calls is not possible. Is there however another way to combine multiple macro calls? I was thinking of the following:
let filename = std::env!("FILE_PATH");
let mutated_file_contents = mutate_file!(filename);

...

#[proc_macro]
pub fn static_encrypt_file(tokens: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    for token in tokens {
        println!("{}", token);
    }
}

In the  mutate_file macro, I want to load the file, do some mutations, and return the contents. However, instead of the path to the file, filename as a symbol is passed to the macro.
So the question is: Is it possible to combine multiple macros or should macros not have any dependencies to other macros?
If the latter is the case, it would make a lot of macro code less generic (for instance if I load the specific env variable in the mutate_file macro, I would need to create another identical macro if I wanted to reuse the functionality for another file).

You can define a function for the same functionality and call it in multiple macros, which I think solves the reuse issue.

You say mutate_file macro, but only show a static_encrypt_file macro, is that the same one and you just mistyped?

If so, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve; filename is a variable, not the actual path of the file. mutate_file won't ever be able to read the file at build time, because it does not know the name of the file. All it knows is that a variable filename exists, but not what its content are. Only at Runtime will that be known.

Also note that mutating something global in a proc macro is generally a bad idea, as proc-macros have no guarantees whatsoever how, where and if they run.
